# Rigid body on animated mesh is not updating

Tags: animation, rigidbody

Hi I have this ring interacting with the neck of the character. It should update to the movement of the neck but for some reason it behaves as if the neck was always at the position of the first frame an the ring just slides without moving left or right.

I've tried deleting the backed and rebeaking but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas if I'm missing here something?
Thanks in advance

Edit: Based on the comments feedback , I created this repo https://github.com/RDaneelOlivav/animation_tests, where I create the same scene with a generic animated character in mixamo and the same ring:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit2: I applied the deforming in the animate dmesh an dit works much better. Its still behaving a bit wired, because eteh ring doesn't rest on the top of the neck, which I don't really know how to fix that. I increased the sensibility to 0.0015 but I don't quite know what to do to improve this.

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file, because it could be a lot of reasons. Rigid body animations are pretty complex and depend not only on settings in rigid body, but also in things like applied scale, mesh topology etc.

Comment: As @Chris says.. ideally, with a reduced case that still shows the problem.. maybe a simple cylinder  and ring.. that should help you debug, too.

Comment: Hello maybe share your file?

Comment: Hi, Sorry about teh late response:

Comment: Hi, here you have the repo with an example with a generic mixamo animated model https://github.com/RDaneelOlivav/animation_tests . I've edited the question also with more details

Answer (score 0):

Indicate for both meshes, the collision system should take deform modifiers into account:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I had just to adjust the sensitivity to try and make it fall better as a ring would do, but still not quite there. But at least it doesn't behave super strange. I posted the new result in the question.